# How do I place table below plot so that category matches axis ranges?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, spacing, formatting, tikz-external

Here is something that I'm trying to do is to align my table with x-axis category or range so that column below the x range is corresponding of the data

[image]

So As example is shown, I want to create table column between given x ranges.

My code so far

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{semilogxaxis}[
%xtick= {0.001,0.005,0.01,0.05,0.1,0.5,1.0,5.0,10.0,50.0,100.0},
ytick= {0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100},
xmin=0.001, 
ymin =0, 
ymax =100, 
xmax = 100,
max space between ticks=10,
grid=both,
y post scale=1.3,
x post scale=2.5,
log ticks with fixed point,
%x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=\,},
minor y tick num=1,
extra x ticks={0.005,0.05,0.5,5,50},
extra x tick labels={$0.005$,$0.05$,$0.5$,$5$,$50$}
]

\addplot table[x=b,y=a, col sep=comma] {somedata.csv};
\legend{some}
\end{semilogxaxis}
```